# Lg g3 smart cleaning stops working occasionally

Tags: applications, default-applications, system-apps

I use LG G3 and I periodically cleanup my phone with the inbuilt smart cleaning but from 1-2 weeks now when I click on delete temporary files the app stops working and every time I try to do that it happends. One more thing it is also trying to delete apps chache could it be because of this? Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Go to **Setting**
Open **Developer Options**
Under **Apps**, uncheck the box **Don't Keep activities**

Voila....